# R Extract rows with values greater than previous columns

Tags: r

I have a dataframe `values` as shown below

```
row.names  January  February  March
A1         0.02345  0.03456   0.04567
A2         0.07654  0.06543   0.05432
A3         0.02345  0.03456   0.04567
```

I need to extract rows with column values greater than the previous columns
We can see that for A1 and A3, the column values are greater than the previous values. i.e. 0.02345<0.03456<0.04567

```
row.names  January  February  March
A1         0.02345  0.03456   0.04567
A3         0.02345  0.03456   0.04567
```

Need help to extract the rows with the above requirement.

Comment: Hm.. it seems like in all of the rows this condition holds. Why `A2` doesn't satisfy the condition?

Comment: Also, share your attempts at solving this in R code.

Comment: oops! i m sorry A2 is supposed to be in the reverse order

Comment: See, also, `?is.unsorted`

Comment: @alexis_laz nice one. You probably mean something like `indx <- !apply(data, 1, is.unsorted) ; data[indx, ]`. Never heard of this function before.

Comment: @alexis_laz I'll add this to the answer if you don't mind

Comment: @DavidArenburg: Go ahead; I, initially, wanted to comment on your answer to add an alternative to `diff > 0`, but I added the comment here by accident.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a possible approach

```
indx <- colSums(apply(data, 1L, diff) > 0L) == (ncol(data) - 1L)
data[indx, ]
#    January February   March
# A1 0.02345  0.03456 0.04567
# A3 0.02345  0.03456 0.04567
```

A simpler version (see @alexis_laz comment) is to use the built in `unsorted` function

```
indx <- !apply(data, 1, is.unsorted) 
data[indx, ]
```